# Calculate average grades, excluding the entered values that are the lowest and greatest

Tags: c#, exception, average

The task is to allow the user to enter values between 0 and 100. If the user enters -99 the program should stop. Once the program has exited, the average must be computed. However, the average should include all the entered values, except the lowest value entered (minimum) and the greatest value entered (maximum). I have written a fairly good-looking code, but it throws an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Here is that code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DisplayApp();

        Calculate();
    }

    static void DisplayApp()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Grade Calculator: ");

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static double Calculate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter grades (-99 to exit): ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        int[] array1 = new int[] { };

        int iInput = int.Parse(input);

        int min = 100;
        int max = 0;

        int i = 0;

        int sum = 0;
        double average = 0;

        while(iInput != 99)
        {
            if(iInput < min)
            {
                array1[i] = min;
            }
            else if(iInput > max)
            {
                array1[i] = max;
            }

            sum += iInput - (min + max);

            i++;
        }

        average = (double)sum / i;

        return average;
    }
}
```

What do you think could be improved in order for the program to work?

Comment: `int[] array1 = new int[] { };` creates an empty array with size of zero. Array size needs to be known at creation. For dynamic data, you could use a `List`.

Comment: `while(iInput != 99)` should be `-99`, isn't it... Also while loop should have `ReadLine` in it...

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, you create an array of size zero. I don't see why you need an array at all, since you are only summing the values:

```
static double Calculate()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter grades (-99 to exit): ");

    int min = Int32.MaxValue;
    int max = Int32.MinValue;

    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        // TODO: Change to TryParse and handle input errors.
        int iInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (iInput == -99) break;

        if (iInput > 0 && iInput < 100) {
            if (iInput < min)
            {
                min = iInput;
            }
            if (iInput > max)
            {
                max = iInput;
            }
            sum += iInput;
            i += 1;
        }
    }

    // TODO: Ensure no division by zero
    return (double)(sum - max - min) / (i - 2);
}
```

Comment: @Rahul No, it's set to `MinValue` so any value the user enters will be larger (or equal) to it and `max` will be set.

Comment: @zaimoff I forgot to move `Console.ReadLine()`. Fixed.

Comment: Still does not work, thank you for trying to help though.

Comment: Can you explain "does not work"? Tested ok for me: https://ideone.com/YznK3g

Comment: It worked, sorry for that. I had messed up a line of code.